# Mongoose custom instance method not working

Tags: express, mongoose

I've added one mongoose instance method on my app User model to compare password when user logins. But the method is not working and throwing error with message

> "user.checkPassword is not a function"

login controller method:

```
exports.login = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;
  if (!email || !password) {
    throw new BadRequest("Please provide email or password.");
  }
  const user = await User.find({ email });
  if (!user) {
    throw new Unauthenticated("Invalid Credentials");
  }
  const isPasswordCorrect = await user.checkPassword(password);
  if (!isPasswordCorrect) {
    throw new UnauthenticatedError("Invalid credentials");
  }
  const token = user.createJWT();
  res.status(StatusCodes.CREATED).json({ user: { user: user.name }, token });
};
```

instance method in model:

```
userSchema.methods.checkPassword = async function (candidatePassword) {
  let isCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password);
  return isCorrect;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`Model.find()` will return an array of documents even though the query result contains only one document. The instance methods are added to the document, **not** the array. That's why you got the error.

Try using `Model.findOne()` method:

```
const user = await User.findOne({ email });
```

It will return one document.